# Python Threading Joining a Dead Thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

What happens if I call `join()` on a thread that has already finished?

e.g.

```
import threading
import time

def fn():
    time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=fn)
t.start()

time.sleep(2)
t.join()
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) don't seem to provide any clarity on this issue

Comment: the call is non-blocking and it skips to end/next instruction.

Comment: It just returns immediately in that case.

Comment: Why not try yourself :)

Comment: @NimishBansal, yep, it's not too hard to try. I'm just wondering if this behavior is officially defined so I can count on it every time. I assumed, as others have pointed out, that the call would return immediately, but I kinda wish the docs were a little more explicit.

Comment: Ya actually regarding dead thread I would have rather ask how to re-start the dead thread,since thread.start() raises exception :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the docs you quoted:

> join:
>   Wait until the thread terminates. ...

so if the thread is already terminated, of course, it exits at once.

Somewhere else from the docs as well:

> the operation will block until the thread terminates.

ok so if it's already terminated, the operation doesn't block.

This method is a way to provide synchronization between the caller and the thread. After `join` exits, it's guaranteed that the thread ended. If the thread is already over when `join` is called, then of course, it does nothing.

This is confirmed by the [python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py) (this function is called from `join()`:

```
def _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block=True, timeout=-1):
    # Issue #18808: wait for the thread state to be gone.
    # At the end of the thread's life, after all knowledge of the thread
    # is removed from C data structures, C code releases our _tstate_lock.
    # This method passes its arguments to _tstate_lock.acquire().
    # If the lock is acquired, the C code is done, and self._stop() is
    # called.  That sets ._is_stopped to True, and ._tstate_lock to None.
    lock = self._tstate_lock
    if lock is None:  # already determined that the C code is done
        assert self._is_stopped   # we see that we don't wait for anything here
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
        lock.release()
        self._stop()
```

Comment: That was my assumption. The documentation just seemed a little vague

Comment: It would be nice if the docs were more explicit, like the man page for `pthread_join`: "If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns immediately."

Comment: @FredLarson yes, wouldn't hurt.

Comment: from the docs as well: "the operation will block until the thread terminates." ok so if it's already terminated, the operation doesn't block.

Comment: I mean, if you wanted to split hairs, the thread never actually terminates after join() is called (because it was already terminated), which would imply join() would block forever.

Comment: the system checks if the thread is still running. If it's not, it exits immediately. Else that would be a deadlock. It's easy to avoid that deadlock, so the system avoids it.

Comment: JohannB has it. The docs do not say what happens if the thread is dead. They all assume the thread will terminate. A dead thread will never terminate so it's just as valid an interpretation to say "it will never return" or "the behavior is undefined". This latter can't even be shown wrong by a test because it might just be passing by coincidence.

Comment: `join` isn't going to block forever if the thread is already terminated, it makes no sense.